# Unable to clone subprojects in gitlab after upgrading to version 9

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to clone subgroup repository in gitlab but when I am trying to clone I am getting

> /info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

I am getting this error only for subgroups in gitlab.

I am not sure what I am missing here, I checked the repository URL everything is working fine. I don't have option to connect via ssh as it is disabled in our environment.